# Remove columns in data frame containing common character name

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidy

I have a dataframe in r that has multiple columns with similar characters in the name, as an example:

```
  tom_wa = c(1,1,1);
  tom_ba = c(2,2,2);
  jim_wa = c(3,3,3);
  jim_ba = c(4,4,4);
  df <- data.frame(tom_wa, tom_ba, jim_wa, jim_ba)
```

The actual data frame has over 30 columns, is there a concise way where I can filter out columns only containing "_ba" or the "_wa"?

Comment: `df %>% select(-contains("_ba"))`

Comment: With "filter out" do you mean that you want to remove those columns? Or do you want to keep them?

Comment: This is fundamental operation using [`dplyr::select`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select.html). While SO is definitely a good place for questions, this question seems like it would be resolved by doing dplyr's [Getting Started](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/dplyr.html) tutorial/walk-through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  select(ends_with(c("ba", "wa")))
```

Answer (score 1):

With base R, you can do like this:

```
df[grep("_(b|w)a", names(df))]
```